# How to disambiguate text with ANTLR4 that is sometimes two tokens, and sometime a third one?

Tags: antlr4, lexer, disambiguation

I have a problem with ANTLR4 grammar. I need to parse a text that contains 6 AN characters.
Based on the context of the text, it can represent:
 - a 6-AN identifier (flight reservation number - PNR - which looks like 7B22MS, or JPN92Y, or similar),
 - airline designator (two letters) + flight number (four number), e.g. LH1856.

The problem is that if I create lexer rules that parse airline, number and PNR identifier like this:

Airline : 'A'..'Z''A'..'Z';

FlNum : ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9');

PNR : ('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9');

then the PNR rule always wins and eats all the tokens that match its pattern.

How can I change this so that the Airline and FlNum will be parsed, if the context of the grammar needs them?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
AirlineAndFlNm : 'A'..'Z' 'A'..'Z' ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9');

PNR : ('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')('A'..'Z'|'0'..'9');
```

or more readable:

```
AirlineAndFlNm : LETTER LETTER DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT ;

PNR : AlphaNum AlphaNum AlphaNum AlphaNum AlphaNum AlphaNum;

// fragments can only be used by other rules, will never create a token on their own
fragment LETTER: 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment AlphaNum: LETTER | DIGIT ;
```

It should be easy to separate `AirlineAndFlNm` afterwards.
And since `AirlineAndFlNm` is placed before `PNR`, it will match if it can.

Answer (score 0):

Let the lexer tokenize single characters and promote these rules to parser rules:

```
// parser rules

airline
 : LETTER
 ;

fl_num
 : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT
 ;

pnr
 : alpha_num alpha_num alpha_num alpha_num alpha_num alpha_num
 ;

alpha_num
 : DIGIT
 | LETTER
 ;

// lexer rules

DIGIT
 : [0-9]
 ;

LETTER
 : [A-Z]
 ;
```